# AWS iOS SDK crashing with carthage update for version 2.5.8

Tags: ios, git, amazon-web-services, carthage

I have been working on a project that requires access to the github repository aws/aws-sdk-ios for some time now and make use of many of its features.

Recently, when trying to build the project in Swift, I have been getting the following build failure:

**Use of unresolved identifier AWSBasicCredentialsProvider**

The code has remain unchanged from when it was working previously, save a few completely unrelated changes for the Mapbox features I also use for the project. Deciding it was most probably an issue with my version of the aws sdk for ios, I typed the following commands in the terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.*.CarthageKit
rm -rf Carthage
carthage update --platform ios
```

The resulting output is:

**A shell task (/usr/bin/env git checkout --quiet --force 2.5.8) failed with exit code 1:**

**error: pathspec '2.5.8' did not match any file(s) known to git**

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? All help is greatly appreciated!

For reference, my Cartfile is as follows:

```
github "SwiftyBeaver/SwiftyBeaver"
github "Mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios"
github "Mapbox/MapboxDirections.swift"
github "Mapbox/MapboxGeocoder.swift"
github "aws/aws-sdk-ios"
```

Comment: Hello, does this problem still persist? Can you retry or provide steps to reproduce? Does it fail for any specific service?

Comment: Rohan Dubal, yes, the problem is still persisting. It seems to be failing solely for the aws-sdk-ios services. Removing the line in the Cartfile corresponding to these services allows everything else to complete as normally.

Comment: Can you specify:
-Carthage version
-Xcode version
-iOS target version

Comment: Absolutely, Carthage version 0.23.0 Xcode version 8.3.2 and Target iOS version 10.3.2

Answer (score 0):

The Cartfile.resolved file has the content as follows:

> ```
> github "52inc/Pulley" "1.4"
> github "Mapbox/MapboxDirections.swift" "v0.9.1"
> github "Mapbox/MapboxGeocoder.swift" "v0.6.2"
> github "Mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios" "v0.4.0"
> github "Project-OSRM/osrm-text-instructions.swift" "v0.1.2"
> github "SwiftyBeaver/SwiftyBeaver" "1.2.2"
> github "aws/aws-sdk-ios" "2.4.3"
> github "frederoni/aws-sdk-ios" "1a8432b03c22326fb7ed86fac978212106e2d465"
> github "raphaelmor/Polyline" "v4.1.1"
> github "rs/SDWebImage" "4.0.0"
> ```

One of your dependencies

> "Mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios"

depends on a different version of aws-sdk-ios

Look here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios/blob/master/Cartfile

Clearly, this is a namespace issue which causes carthage update failures.